# Задаю такой параметр User createUser = new User();. последние скобки подчеркиваются и всплывает сообщение приведенное ниже,

Tags: java

> User() in User cannot be applied to: Expected Parameters: Actual
>   Arguments:   name: Name
>
> surname: Surname
>
> age: int

Как решается такая проблема?

Answer (score 5):

```
User createUser = new User("John", "Smith", 35);
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте пустой конструктор в класс `User` и будет вам счастье!

```
public User(){};
```